# Understanding Data frames in Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

Can anyone explain me what this function is doing? Like I know it checks if a row in csv is duplicate or not. But, I only want to check if a particular column has duplicate values or not. How do I do that?

```
@Validator
def hasDuplicates( fileInDf, fileType = File_Name_All, kwargs = def_kwargs ):
    ''' Return row indexes that are duplicates '''
    import pandas

    if fileInDf is None:
        return ValidatorResponse( rule_decision = Rule_Decision.INVALID_INPUT, rule_return_message = 'Input File is not a valid file for rule : hasDuplicates' )
    if type( fileInDf ) is not pandas.DataFrame:
        return ValidatorResponse( rule_decision = Rule_Decision.INVALID_INPUT, rule_return_message = 'Type %s is not a valid DataFrame Type for rule : hasDuplicates' % type( fileInDf ))
    if fileInDf.empty:
        return ValidatorResponse( rule_decision = Rule_Decision.INVALID_INPUT, rule_return_message = 'Input File is not a valid file for rule : hasDuplicates' )

    dups = fileInDf.duplicated()
    indexes = dups[ dups == True ].index.tolist()
    fixedDf = fileInDf.drop_duplicates()

    ret = Rule_Decision.FAILED if len( fixedDf ) != len( fileInDf ) else Rule_Decision.SUCCESS
    return ValidatorResponse( rule_decision = ret, rule_return_fixedDf = fixedDf, rule_return_val = indexes )
```

UPDATE:

```
@Validator
def hasDuplicatesSingleColumn( val, fileInDf, fileType = File_Name_All, kwargs = def_kwargs ):
    ''' Return row indexes that are duplicates '''
    import pandas

    if fileInDf is None:
        return ValidatorResponse( rule_decision = Rule_Decision.INVALID_INPUT, rule_return_message = 'Input File is not a valid file for rule : hasDuplicates' )
    if type( fileInDf ) is not pandas.DataFrame:
        return ValidatorResponse( rule_decision = Rule_Decision.INVALID_INPUT, rule_return_message = 'Type %s is not a valid DataFrame Type for rule : hasDuplicates' % type( fileInDf ))
    if fileInDf.empty:
        return ValidatorResponse( rule_decision = Rule_Decision.INVALID_INPUT, rule_return_message = 'Input File is not a valid file for rule : hasDuplicates' )

    col_dups = fileInDf[['column']].duplicated()
    indexes = col_dups[ col_dups == True ].index.tolist()
    new_df = fileInDf[['column']].drop_duplicates()

    ret = Rule_Decision.FAILED if len( new_df ) != len( fileInDf ) else Rule_Decision.SUCCESS
    return ValidatorResponse( rule_decision = ret, rule_return_fixedDf = new_df, rule_return_val = indexes )
```

But, how do I get the indexes? Is it the correct way in the above function?

Comment: Can you provide some context? Where do things like `Validator` and `ValidatorResponse` come from? Are you using a particular package in addition to Pandas?

Answer (score 1):

You just want to know whether there are duplicates for a certain column? There's a few ways of doing that. Here's a simple one:

```
len(fileInDf.groupby('column').sum()) == len(fileInDf['column'])
```

will return `True` only if there are no duplicate values in the column.

Another one is to create a single-column dataframe and use `drop_duplicates` there:

```
new_df = fileInDf[['column']].drop_duplicates()
```

and now see whether the two have the same length

```
len(new_df) == len(fileInDf)
```

Finally, you can use `duplicated` like this:

```
True in fileInDf[['column']].duplicated()
```

if there is a value that is duplicated, then that statment will return `True`

Note that `fileInDf[['column']]` produces a data frame consisting of one column, and is different than `fileInDf['column']`, which produces a Series object.

Comment: And can you please check my updated code. Is that the correct way? Also, how and where do I specify which column I want to check for duplicates?